# Detect nearest location from Array of Locations by using Google Map APIs

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've an array of locations:  {'**place1**', '**place2**', '**place3**'}   **// these are addresses*

Now assume that there is a new location: '**place4**'.

I want to detect which one is nearest to '**place4**'....comparing from above array of locations....

i.e. tracking nearest location of a point from array of locations...(By using Google Map APIs)..

psuedo code:

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
     var i = TrackNearestLocationByGoogleMapAPIs(item);
     if(i is nerest)
     {
       print(i);  and go out of loop...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API-call to do what you want. You have to calculate the distance yourself with the Haversine formula as seen here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Maps API v3 provides a simple mechanism to do this.  You might be able to retrieve the latitude and longitude of each location and figure out which point is the closest from that data.